# C++ list, get number of elements in a list?

Tags: c++, list

Quick question.
I've got a list and I simply added just one element to the `list`.
But when I print out `myList.size()`, it returns `18`? Even though there is one element?

To add my element I use: `myList.push_back(element)`;

Comment: How did you construct your list?

Comment: Could you post the code that does this (i.e. creates the list, pushes an element, and prints a size of 18)?

Comment: It's a pity that we have four answers of people having to guess about your code. Why don't you... show us your question first?

Answer (score 6):

§23.3.6 says:

> The member function `size()` returns the number of elements in the container.

This means that

- 1) you have a broken C++ environment, or
- 2) you have, somehow, added more elements to your list.

Unfortunately, it's hard to tell which is the case, as you haven't posted enough information. What would be nice is a small, complete, examples that demonstrates what you are trying to do, a description of what happens and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility that i can think of is that the list has been created with a finite size using the following constructor :

```
explicit list ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you want to do something like this...I performed a quick search and found the following..

```
int main ()
{
    list<int> myints;
    cout << "0. size: " << (int) myints.size() << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) myints.push_back(i);
    cout << "1. size: " << (int) myints.size() << endl;

    myints.insert (myints.begin(),10,100);
    cout << "2. size: " << (int) myints.size() << endl;

    myints.pop_back();
    cout << "3. size: " << (int) myints.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the start do `MyList.clear()` then push the elements and finally check the size.